# Is "take" used with food?

Tags: word-usage

Do people in some English speaking regions use "take" with food in this way: "I took eggs for breakfast"?

I can see it being used for a meal in old-fashioned American English, as in "I'll take breakfast on the porch," but it sounds strange to me in combination with particular dishes or food items.

Comment: Much depends on the *exact* context. It wouldn't be unusual to say *I'll take scrambled eggs instead of cornflakes* to someone serving you in a cafeteria queue, for example. But as you obviously know, ***have*** is far more common for most speakers in most contexts. Which certainly doesn't rule out alternatives such as *I **went for** porridge this morning for a change.*

Comment: My grandmother, who was born in 1901 and raised in Beaumont, Texas, used to say, "Do you take cereal for breakfast?" It is not something I ever heard anyone else say in the United States or in the UK. I've always thought she said that because her father was French. In French (and this is similar in other Romance languages), the question would be, "Prenez-vous des céréales au petit déjeuner ?" with the verb "prendre" meaning "to take". My grandmother was not raised speaking French, and I don't believe her father spoke very good English. But he might have used "take" in that way.

Comment: Additionally, I believe that there are people today who say, "Do you take cream and sugar?" I actually think I say that myself. But that is one usage confined to coffee or tea.

Comment: @IsabelArcher Indeed, _take sugar_ is the standard expression for habitually putting it in your hot drink.

Comment: It's not real common, but easily understood in context, and it's perfectly normal for some people to use this sort of wording in casual conversation, because they were raised hearing it or some such.  Not really worth getting your shorts in a twist about.

Comment: "Taking" food is actually fairly common in UK usage, especially when a nuance of accepting or preferring is intended, e.g. invalids may be persuaded to take milky puddings, I always take my steaks with mustard.

Comment: Also said of sick people, e.g., She was able to take a little soup.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S, one often uses **take** in the context of *selecting* particular dishes or food items. From M-W:

**[take](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take)**: to pick out; CHOOSE, SELECT

For example, when presented with a menu or set of options, one might say:

> I'll take the chicken fajitas.
>
> I'll take the breakfast: eggs, scrambled; ham; home fries; and toast, rye.
>
> I'll take the ribeye, medium rare, with the standard house sides.
>
> I'll take a dozen doughnuts: three glazed, three chocolate cake, three chocolate-covered, and three cinnamon.